# "reasons to" vs "reasons for"

Tags: differences, prepositions

Which of the following is the better or more correct usage when the noun *reason* is plural?

> I can't do it. There are several reasons **to** it.

vs

> I can't do it. There are several reasons **for** it.

Comment: I assume " reasons for " would be better to be followed by a gerund.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Reason*, both in the singular and in the plural, is used in conjunction with both *to* and *for*, but in different ways:

1. *To* is used when the complement of *reason* is a **verbal phrase**; the verb is in the infinitive. “There are several reasons *to do it*”, for example.
2. *For* is used when the complement is a **noun phrase**. This includes verbal nouns and gerunds, both of which are nominalised forms of verbal phrases, so it's not like *for* can't be used with anything that has something essentially verbal in it—but if the head of the complement is morphologically nominal rather than verbal, you must use *for*. Example: “There are several reasons for doing it.”

In your example, the compliment is *that* (actually, you wrote *it*, but *that* is what you would more idiomatically say in English), which is a pronoun, i.e., something nominal. Therefore, you must use *for* rather than *to* in your example.

Answer (score 1):

@Janus Bahs Jacquet is technically right about the formal grammar here, but there's something to be said about the usage of ***to*** in relation to pronouns that is idiomatic in nature, and thus makes this question more complicated than it seems at first glance.

For example, let's look at the idiomatic phrase "there's something to him/her/it" where ***to*** is a synonym for ***with respect to him***, and when it's paraphrased more clearly has the meaning of "there's some quality he/she/ it has that draws attention to them".

In the asker's example "There are several reasons for that" (replaced *it* with *that* as per Janus), that "***that***" refers to the preceding implied gerund phrase "not being capable/willing of doing it", i.e. "There are several reasons for my not being capable/willing of doing it".

But the asker's first example "There are several reasons to it", the ***it*** *doesn't* refer to the preceding implied gerund phrase "not being capable/willing of doing it", but *instead* is used idiomatically in the same sense as the idiomatic phrase "there's something to him/her/it" to mean "There are several reasons (with respect to) the previously stated sentence that is 'I can't do it'."

So, you see, even though it is not standard usage in the formally grammatical sense that Janus pointed out, it is acceptable in an idiomatic sense, that is, if the reader can catch it.

And it has been used before in contexts like this in books:

[At Home in Many Worlds: Reading, Writing and Translating from Chinese and Jewish Cultures](https://books.google.com/books?id=Esz2vwNkzNMC&pg=PA179&dq=%22reasons+to+it%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiMoaWJjorOAhXiy4MKHaw5AXAQ6AEIHDAA#v=onepage&q=%22reasons%20to%20it%22&f=false)

[image]

(the "it" here referring to the fact that he is adhering to the established usage)

[The Middle English Mystery Play: A Study in Dramatic Speech and Form](https://books.google.com/books?id=U_abU8UmT34C&pg=PA60&dq=%22reasons+to+it%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiBl5fKmYrOAhUHyoMKHSjcCNEQ6AEIKDAC#v=onepage&q=%22reasons%20to%20it%22&f=false)

[image]

(the "it" here referring to the fact that he entrusted his treasures)

Comment: In the second example, I read the _it_ as referring to the statue and _to it_ being a complement of _explains_, that is, he explains his reasons and plans to the statue. The first example just strikes me as very, very unnatural. In my English, it would be ungrammatical.